# How to get DOM event listeners using java

Tags: java, javascript, dom, htmlunit, web-crawler

I'm trying to build a crawler that can handle AJAX application. I'm using htmlunit to browse programmatically.

- I can't find a way to get all the event listeners assigned to some
  DOM element. I don't like my crawler to try blindly invoking events
  on each DOM-Element.
- So I decided to override the javascript addEventListner function, so
  it can keep a registry of event listeners. The question is: how to
  inject this modified javascript code, and make sure that it's first
  thing running when page loaded?
- The other question: Is there a better way to solve this, I wish there
  is function like  getEventListners(domElement).

The crawler need to know the events assigned to the DOM-Elements without triggering the event.

Answer (score 1):

You can override addEventListener method like this:

```
// Create a copy or addEventListener for subsequent calls
HTMLElement.prototype.realAddEventListener = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener;

// This array should contains all listeners added to each element
HTMLElement.prototype.allListeners = [];

HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = function(a,b,c){
    this.realAddEventListener(a,b,c); 
    this.allListeners.push({a : a, b : b , c : c});
};
```

you can get all listeners calling allListeners property on every HTMLElement on the page.

Comment: The question is: how to inject this modified javascript code, and make sure that it's first thing running when page loaded?... The Request made programmatically like this: webClient.getPage("http://localhost/....."); * I NEED TO INJECT THE overridden addEventListener method IN THE RESPONSE to be executed before the original addEventLitener BEEN INVOKED.

Comment: I think that you can use ScriptPreprocesor to achieve this task: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/ScriptPreProcessor.html

Comment: Thanks,,, this looks promising, I'll run some tests.